# WPF avoiding xmlns redundancy

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xml-namespaces

Just wondering, any way we can use inheritance in the namespace section of a WPF user control.
The problem statement is, I end up copy and pasting following block of xaml lines in all my views, Is there some mechanism to put this namespace declarations in some file and derive in all views?

```
xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="{StaticResource DefaultAssemblyName}"
lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="Strings"
```

Comment: I must say that condensing several namespace declarations into one (which is what the answer on the other question is doing) is helpful and practical, but doesn't allow you to set default values for attached properties like those @Shanadas is using

Comment: The answer to the suggested duplicate question doesn't address this question, so I reopened it.